# Deploying helm charts via Terraform Helm provider and Azure DevOps while fetching the helm charts from ACR

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, kubernetes-helm, terraform-provider-azure, azure-container-registry

I am trying to deploy the helm charts from ACR to an AKS cluster using Terraform helm provider and Azure DevOps container job but it fails while fetching the helm chart from ACR. Please let me know what is going wrong.

helm provider tf module:

```
data "helm_repository" "cluster_rbac_helm_chart_repo" {
  name = "mcp-rbac-cluster"
  url  = "https://mcpshareddcr.azurecr.io"
}
# Deploy Cluster RBAC helm chart onto the cluster
resource "helm_release" "cluster_rbac_helm_chart_release" {
  name  = "mcp-rbac-cluster"
  repository = data.helm_repository.cluster_rbac_helm_chart_repo.metadata[0].name
  chart = "mcp-rbac-cluster"
}
```

provider:

```
  version                    = "=1.36.0"
  tenant_id                  = var.ARM_TENANT_ID
  subscription_id            = var.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
  client_id                  = var.ARM_CLIENT_ID
  client_secret              = var.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
  skip_provider_registration = true
}

data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster" {
  name                = var.aks_cluster
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_aks
}

locals {
  kubeconfig_path = "/tmp/kubeconfig"
}

resource "local_file" "kubeconfig" {
  filename = local.kubeconfig_path
  content  = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster.kube_admin_config_raw
}

provider "helm" {
  home = "resources/.helm"
  kubernetes {
    load_config_file = true
    config_path = local.kubeconfig_path
  }
}

module "aks_resources" {
  source = "./modules/helm/aks-resources"
}
```

error:
**Error: Looks like "**" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Failed to fetch **/index.yaml : 404 Not Found**

Comment: At a glance I'd say that `data.helm_repository.cluster_rbac_helm_chart_repo.metadata[0].name` should be `data.helm_repository.cluster_rbac_helm_chart_repo.metadata.0.name` but not 100% sure. Would be useful if you could show the full error you are getting as well instead of the extract in your question currently.

Answer (score 5):

Until now, Helm still doesn't support directly installing chart from an OCI registry.

The recommended steps are:

1. `helm chart remove mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/helm/hello-world:v1`
2. `helm chart pull mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/helm/hello-world:v1`
3. `helm chart export mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/helm/hello-world:v1 --destination ./install`
4. `cd install & helm install myhelmtest ./hello-world`

So my solution is:

```
resource "null_resource" "download_chart" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      export HELM_EXPERIMENTAL_OCI=1
      helm registry login mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io --username someuser --password somepass
      helm chart remove mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/helm/hello-world:v1
      helm chart pull mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/helm/hello-world:v1
      helm chart export mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/helm/hello-world:v1 --destination ./install
    EOT
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "chart" {
  name             = "hello_world"
  repository       = "./install"
  chart            = "hello-world"
  version          = "v1"

  depends_on = [null_resource.download_chart]
}
```

Not perfect but works.

Comment: Note: The Terraform Helm provider >=[v2.5.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-helm/releases/tag/v2.5.0) does now support OCI registries

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you use the wrong `url` in the Terraform helm_repository. The right `url` for ACR looks like this:

```
https://acrName.azurecr.io/helm/v1/repo
```

And the ACR is a private registry, so it means you need to add the username and password for it. Finally, your Terraform code should like this with version 2.0+ of helm provider:

```
resource "helm_release" "my-chart" {
  name  = "my-chart"
  chart = "my/chart"
  repository  = "https://${var.acr_name}.azurecr.io/helm/v1/repo"
  repository_username = var.acr_user_name
  repository_password = var.acr_user_password
}
```

Or with 1.x helm provider:

```
data "helm_repository" "cluster_rbac_helm_chart_repo" {
  name = "mcp-rbac-cluster"
  url  = "https://mcpshareddcr.azurecr.io/helm/v1/repo"

  username = "xxxxx"
  password = "xxxxx"
}

# Deploy Cluster RBAC helm chart onto the cluster
resource "helm_release" "cluster_rbac_helm_chart_release" {
  name  = "mcp-rbac-cluster"
  repository = data.helm_repository.cluster_rbac_helm_chart_repo.metadata[0].name
  chart = "mcp-rbac-cluster"
}
```

**Update**

Here is the screenshot that it works well and deploy the charts in the AKS:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did put the URL as above and it reached the ACR and failed with 

```Error: Looks like "***/helm/v1/repo" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Failed to fetch ***/helm/v1/repo/index.yaml : 401 Unauthorized ```

In my case I can't provide the username and password directly in the terraform file since I am using the service principal via the azure devops pipeline so is there any mean i can pass the username and password from the pipeline to the tf file rather then writing it in file ?

Comment: @user3616775 Do you read the answer carefully? I said you need to add the username and password of your ACR.

Comment: yes i read that but i can't pass it directly

```
        - bash: 'terraform init -input=false'
          env:
            TF_VAR_ARM_ACCESS_KEY: $(storage_access_key)
            TF_VAR_ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(AZURE_CLIENT_ID)
            TF_VAR_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET)
            TF_VAR_ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
            TF_VAR_ARM_TENANT_ID: $(AZURE_TENANT_ID)
            TF_LOG: DEBUG
          displayName: 'terraform init'
     ```

Comment: @user3616775 Do you set the credential of your ACR in the Terraform? It's not the sp credential, it's the ACR's.

Comment: @user3616775 Do you solve the problem? If the answer works for you, please accept it.

Comment: yes the sp has an acrpull access because in our case we can't assign an access to an individual. I have set it  via env variable through the pipeline and now it works as per the authorization but another error came.

```

Error: Looks like "***/helm/v1/repo" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: open resources/.helm/repository/cache/resources/.helm/repository/cache/mcpshareddcr-index.yaml: no such file or directory
```
when i put the helm home in helm provider

Comment: @user3616775 Why not? It works well on my side. I think what caused the error is that you set something wrong in your DevOps, not the Terraform code with my answer.

Comment: @user3616775 What is the situation now? Still the get the error?

Comment: @user3616775 That's great. If you do not mind, please accept the answer.

Comment: @user3616775 Can you give the reason that you do not accept my answer? Doesn't it work for you?!

Comment: Excellent! thanks a lot, added update for v 2.0 of helm provider

Comment: :) @Charles, I'm not the question author so I cannot accept it. Upvote is all I can do for you bud.

Answer (score 0):

Small enhancement to the above solution. Include a trigger to force a download of the chart every time. Otherwise, it expects that you always maintain the local copy of the chart post the first deployment

```
resource "null_resource" "download_chart" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = timestamp()
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      export HELM_EXPERIMENTAL_OCI=1
      helm registry login ${var.registry_fqdn} --username ${var.acr_client_id} --password ${var.acr_client_secret}
      helm chart remove ${var.registry_fqdn}/helm/${var.chart_name}:${var.chart_tag}
      helm chart pull ${var.registry_fqdn}/helm/${var.chart_name}:${var.chart_tag}
      helm chart export ${var.registry_fqdn}/helm/${var.chart_name}:${var.chart_tag} --destination ./install
    EOT
  }
}
```